# How do I find the index at which a given value will be reached/cross by another series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a timeseries of values called `X`.

And I now want to know the first index after which the values of some other series `Y` will be reached by `X`. Or put differently, for each index `i` I want to know the *first* index `j` *after* which the line formed by `X` from `j-1` to `j` intersects the value of `Y` at `i`.

Below is an example set of example `X`, `Y` series, showing the resulting values for `Z`. **The length of these series is always the same**:

```
X | Y   | Z
2 | 3   | 2
2 | 3   | NaN
4 | 4.5 | 3
5 | 5   | NaN
4 | 5   | NaN
3 | 2   | 6
1 | 2   | NaN
```

Do `pandas` or `numpy` offer something that will assist with this? This function will be run on large datasets so I can't use python loops.

Comment: Are the two series always the same shape (length) ?

Comment: Let me know if I understood correctly @quant. Perhaps a larger sample would be more convenient

Comment: @Erfan yes they are always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy broadcasting` by compare with `shifted` values, then get indices of first `True`s by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with small improvement - added `NaN` column for get `NaN` if all `False` values per row and last remove duplicates values:

```
a = df['X']
b = df['Y']

a1 = a.values
a2 = a.shift(-1).ffill().values
b1 = b.values[:, None]

arr = (((a1 < b1) & (a2 > b1)) | ((a1 > b1) & (a2 < b1)))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df[np.nan] = True
out = df.idxmax(axis=1) + 1
out = out.mask(out.duplicated())
print (out)
0    2.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    6.0
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: Very clever. Cheers for this!